# Voting Question: Find Variance

Tags: statistics, variance

> Out of $n$ individual voters at an election, $r$ vote Republican and $n-r$ vote Democrat. At the next election, the probability of a Republican switching to vote Democrat is $p_1$, and a Democrat switching to vote Republican is $p_2$ Suppose individuals behave independently. Find the $Var(X)$ where $X$ = # of Republican votes at the second election.

Let $I_i$ be the indicator that the $i$th person votes for Republican, $1 \le i \le n$

$Var(X)$

$=Var(I_1 + I_2 + \ldots + I_n)$

$=Var(I_1) + Var(I_2) + \ldots + Var(I_n)$ since individuals behave independently.

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(I_i)$

---

$E(I_i) = P(I_i)$

$= P($Voted for Republican$)P($Not Switching | Voted for Republican$) $

$+ P($Voted for Democrat$)P($Switching | Voted for Democrat$)$

$= \frac{r}{n} \cdot (1-p_1) + \frac{n-r}{n} \cdot p_2$

$= \frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n}$

---

$Var(I_i)$

$=E(I_i^2) - (E(I_i))^2$

$= (\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n}) - (\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n})^2$

---

We have:

$Var(X)$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(I_i)$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n}) - (\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n})^2\right)$

$=n\left((\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n}) - (\frac{r(1-p_1)}{n} + \frac{(n-r)p_2}{n})^2\right)$

Textbook Answer:

> $r(1-p_1)p_1+(n-r)p_2(1-p_2)$

I checked the 2 solutions with $p_1 = 0.3, p_2 = 0.4, n = 8, r= 4$ and my solution gave 1.98, but the textbook solution gave 1.8.

Not sure where went wrong because I used the same method for another question and got it right.

---

**Edit 1:**

Let $I_i$ be the indicator that the $i$th person votes for Republican, $1 \le i \le n$

$Var(X)$

$=Var(I_1 + I_2 + \ldots + I_n)$

$P(I_i)$ changes depending on whether the voter is a Republican or a Democrat. And the probability whether they are a Republican or a Democrat depends on the # of Republican/Democrat voters that have voted. Thus, $I_i$ are dependent of each other so $Var(I_1 + I_2 + \ldots + I_n)$ cannot be broken down using the addition rule for variances.

---

New Plan:

Let $X_1$ be the number of Republicans who remains voting for Republican.

Let $X_2$ be the number of Democrats who switch to vote for Republican.

$Var(X)$

$= Var(X_1 + X_2)$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent because the choices of republican voters do not affect the choices of the democrat voters.

$= Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)$

---

Let $I_i$ be the indicator that the $i$th **Republican** voter votes for Republican, $1 \le i \le r$

$Var(X_1)$

$=Var(I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_r)$, this time, $I_i$ is independent of each other because $P(I_i)$ probability of a given Republican voter voting for Republican only depends on the probability of a Republican voter not switching, which is constant $(1-p_1)$.

$=Var(I_1) + Var(I_2) + ... + Var(I_r)$

$= \sum_{i = 1}^{r}Var(I_i)$

$= \sum_{i = 1}^{r}((1-p_1)-(1-p_1)^2)$

$= \sum_{i = 1}^{r}(1-p_1)(1-(1-p_1))$

$= \sum_{i = 1}^{r}(1-p_1)p_1$

$= r(1-p_1)p_1$

---

Same is done for $Var(X_2)$ except instead of "$r$", we have $n-r$ Democrats and we get:

$Var(X)$

$= Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)$

$= r(1-p_1)p_1 + (n-r)(1-p_2)p_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we do not have $\operatorname{Var}(I_1)=\operatorname{Var}(I_n)$ in general.

Suppose the first person voted republican previously, then his current distribution is $Bernoulli(p_1)$

Suppose the $n$-th person voted democrats previously, then his current distribution is $Bernoulli(p_2)$.

We can't assume that $\operatorname{Var}(I_1)=\operatorname{Var}(I_2)$.

There are $r$ people who voted for republican previously is a known fact and it is not the case that everyone equally likely voted for republican with probability $\frac{r}{n}$ previously.

We can assume the first $r$ people voted for republican previously and the remaining $n-r$ people voted for democrats previously.

Guide:

Let $X_1$ be the number of republican who remains voting for republican.

Let $X_2$ be the number of democrats who switch to vote for republican.

Let $X=X_1+X_2$, note that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Think of what distribution does $X_i$ follows.

Comment: I still kind of don't understand why $I_i$ are dependent. Given that the 1st person voted for Republican on the 2nd election, it shouldn't affect the probability of the 2nd person voting for Republican on the 2nd election since they "behave" independently? $P(I_2 | I_1) = P(I_2)$  no?

Comment: hmmm... true let me edit my answer for a while.

Comment: Okay, I think I get why they're not independent, and splitting $X$ in therms of $X_1$ and $X_2$ given in your definition allows us to break down the problem further while maintaining independecy so $Var(X_1 + X_2)$ can be separated.  See **Edit 1**

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming the probability that any two voters were former whatever voters is independent.   That's not the case since there is a fix amount for each in the population (cf: drawing without replacement).

$X$ equals the count of stay voters among the $r$ former Republican voters (call that $Y$), plus the count of switch voters among the $n-r$ former Democrats voters (call that count $Z$).

Then just use bilinearity of (co)variance:$$\mathsf{Var}(X)~{=\mathsf {Var}(Y)+\mathsf {Var}(Z)+2\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)\\=\mathsf {Var}(Y)+\mathsf {Var}(Z)\qquad+0}$$

Now, you may use Indicator random variables to find the variance of these counts *seperately* from first principles.

Alternatively, we can line everyone up so the first $r$ voters were those who voted Republican, while the last $n-r$ voted Democrate.

$$\mathsf E(I_i^2)=\mathsf E(I_i) =\begin{cases} 1-p_1&:& 1\leq i\leq r\\ p_2 &:& r+1\leq i\leq n\end{cases}$$

---

However, you should recognise the counts as being binomial random variables, and immediately know how to find their variance.

$Y\sim\mathcal{Binom}(r,1-p_1), Z\sim\mathcal{Binom}(n-r,p_2)$ and so $${\mathsf{Var}(Y)=r(1-p_1)p_1 \\ \mathsf{Var}(Z)=(n-r)p_2(1-p_2)}$$

---

Though working from first principles is not wrong.